# Oracle HS Other options

Tags: oracle, odbc, heterogeneous-services

Is there any other way to connect to oracle and others (MSSQL, MySQL, etc), other than HS and ODBC. (Oracle 19c).

I've always used HS and ODBC, but there are always one or another problems with these grandfatherly ODBC drivers on linux, either they don't connect to the database or other errors. The question is out of curiosity, is there any other solution to download and send data (and execute SQL CODE (stored procedure)) from PLSQL to another database?

Comment: if you want to send/receive data , there is always the option to use a tool. But if you want to run  code in another database, you need HS . For MSSQL Server there is another option called linked server https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4396/creating-a-sql-server-2014-linked-server-for-an-oracle-11g-database/

Comment: @RobertoHernandez - I think it worth pointing out that MSSQL's "linked server" is the same concept as oracle's HS.  It's just a question of which end is acting as the client to the other.  If oracle is requesting the connection to MSSQL (oracle  is the client to mssql) then you use oracle HS.  If mssql is requesting the connection (mssql is the client to oracle) then you use linked server.  I discuss this in detail at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/the-oracle-transparent-gateway/

Comment: @EdStevens, good point. I just was mentioning as alternative to HS , though both are basically the same.